# Can a login be made using custom post types and custom fields (ACF)?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to make a login system using WordPress custom post types and advanced custom fields?

I've created a custom post type called 'Users' where I have this structure:

- the post title
- user email (a field of type text using ACF)
- user password (a field of type password using ACF)

With the help of these I practically register the users myself as I want to.

My problem is with the structure of the database where is this saved, because of I think I can't login the user from a front login form.

I tried some queries but something doesn't seem right. Can someone help me please with this. I am on the right track or not?

```php
$login_email = $_POST['login_email'];
$login_password = $_POST['login_password'];

$email_sql = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM ".$wpdb->postmeta." WHERE meta_key = %s AND meta_value = %s",'user_email', $login_email));

$pass_sql = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM ".$wpdb->postmeta." WHERE meta_key = %s AND meta_value = %s",'user_password', $login_password));
```

The thing is that both user email and user password are meta_key and they are not the same record and I think I can't make a login based on that. Am I right or there is a way?

Comment: Out of interest, why would you want to bypass using the built in user functionality? Your front-end users can be given a custom role that is excluded from accessing the backend of Wordpress?

Comment: Because I'm using WordPress to make a mobile app. And the app is outside WordPress. I'm making use of the  CMS only for administration purposes. The users won't have access to the WordPress admin. I only need to add them from the admin with custom info.

Comment: You can easily install WP-API which will expose the ability to log-in via a REST service using the built in functionality. Alternatively, you can just use a `meta_query` search passing the username and password. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a Meta Query within Wordpress to query custom fields.

```
$user = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'and',
        array(
            'key' => 'username',
            'value' => $_POST['username'],
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'password',
            'value' => $_POST['password'],
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
));
```

The above will return a single post if the `username` and `password` custom fields match the values provided.

Note: the above code is just for example. You will need to handle hashing of passwords correctly to secure your code etc.

Edit: After a chat with @Anonymous, it turns out it was a little more complicated but the final solution was:

```
$login_email = $_POST['email'];
// Hash the plain text password.
$login_password = wp_hash_password($_POST['password']);

// Find a post with the ACF Custom value that matches our username.
$user_query = new WP_Query(array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'post_type' => 'users', 
    'meta_query' => array( 
        'relation' => 'or', 
        array( 
            'key' => 'email_user', 
            'value' => $login_email, 
            'compare' => '=' 
        ) 
    ) 
)); 
// Check if the user exists.
if ($user_query->have_posts()) { 
    while($user_query->have_posts()){
        // Load the current post.
        $user_query->the_post(); 
        // Get the current post.
        $user = get_post();
        // Get the hashed password from the post.
        $hashed_password = get_post_meta($user->ID, 'password', true); 
        // Compare the hashed passwords.
        if (wp_check_password(wp_hash_password($login_password), $hashed_password)) { 
            echo "logged in successfull"; 
        } else { 
            echo "user found, password incorrect"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This only returns a huge object. I don't understand how this could help me.

Comment: The above returns the post for the user based on the custom fields setup within ACF. After that you'll need to handle the rest (hence why I suggested using the default functionality.)

Comment: Okay. But what do you mean by "You will need to handle hashing of passwords correctly to secure your code". I'm already hashing the password saved using the custom field. You mean when I compare it?!

Comment: That's correct. My example simply passed in a raw value from the form where as in the database you have hashed the password, so you'll need to hash the raw value before passing it to the query.

Comment: And you think the hashed password from the database can be compared against a hashed password from a user input? Because they won't be the same. Let's say I use wp_hash_password($_POST['password']). If I try to see if there is a match this will never work.

Comment: How won't they be the same? The stored hashed value, will be created using `wp_hash_password` based on your plain text password. When logging in, if you pass that same plain text password to `wp_hash_password` it will return the same value as you stored. The query is then just checking two hashed values, which if the plain text value is the same as that when it was inserted, you'll have a match. I'm assuming you've tried?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I tried. When I'm using the hashed password from the database also as the plain text password it returns the post. Otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111511/discussion-between-gavin-and-anonymous).

Comment: Thanks @Gavin, I answered you on chat. Read that and please change the answer, maybe other people will see it and maybe help them out too.